# React Native preview multiple images on upload

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here... I am trying to upload multiple images using React native on expo. I keep getting an error and my images seem to duplicate.. when I upload one image, two appear...

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])
const [multiImages, setMultiImages] = useState([])

const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            base64: true,
            aspect: [4, 4],
            quality: 0.3,
        })

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            let imageUri = result ? `data:image/jpg;base64,${result.base64}` : null

            multiImages.push(imageUri)
            setImages(multiImages.concat(result.uri))
        }
    }

return(
<>
{images.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <Image key={item + index} style={styles.imageClip} source={{ uri: item }} />
    )})}
</>
)
```

[image: This is what I am trying to archive]

[image: The error I am getting]

Comment: How is Firestore involved in this?

Comment: Yes I am using firestore to store images...

Comment: Ideally you should use Firebase Storage to store images since Firestore documents have 1 MB limit. Also can you share the complete error log? The screenshot just contains the base64 string...

Comment: The error logs as well. `JSON.value(base_64_string...)` isn't clear to explain what's wrong

Comment: Sorry I am using storage for images and linking them back to firestore, but I am getting my error before I run the 'uploadToStorage' via storage function

Comment: True... but unless you share complete error debugging is difficult

Comment: Yes... you right but I can't get a clear error other than that one :(